# How do I go back to my original settings after installing Hola Launcher?

Tags: settings, launcher

I just installed Hola Launcher on my HTC One m8 and it changed everything from my display to content settings. I would like to switch back to exactly how my phone settings were before installing Hola Launcher. I've been trying to find options but to no avail. I would also like to remove Hola Launcher.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you installed Hola Launcher through Play Store so this is what you need to do:

1. Open `Play Store`
2. Go to `My apps`
3. You will see a list of recently installed/updated apps. If you don't see Hola Launcher directly, scroll down and search it in the list.
4. Tap on `Hola Launcher` to access detail information of the app
5. Tap on `Uninstall` (the left button) to uninstall `Hola Launcher`

After that Hola Launcher is completely uninstalled from your device and it should ask you which launcher you want to use, the next time you hit the `Home` button.

Comment: That will only change the default launcher. Not necessarily reset the phone to it's previous state.

Comment: @miva2 this is what I understand of the author's question. If you have a better answer then feel free to add it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happened to me. So, go to the Hola Launcher settings, then the first option will be "Set as default". Turn this option off, then your phone will be back to what it was. Then, go to Play Store, go to My apps, find Hola Launcher, then click uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for my Samsung Galaxy S4.  However, I went to App manager in Settings.  Tapped on the hidden button in the lower-left corner of my screen (in the black area) and tapped on "Uninstall Multiple".  Then tapped the box next to the Hola application and was able to uninstall it.