# How to delete Hola launcher on Intex phone?

Tags: launcher

I can't delete Hola launcher on my Intex smartphone. Once I deleted it from app setting, after some time it's automatically installed again. Another launcher named Launcher3 is on my phone with same problem, it's not removing by factory reset.

How can I delete Hola launcher permanently?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104237/how-do-i-go-back-to-my-original-settings-after-installing-hola-launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Launcher3 is the stock launcher. You can't remove it without rooting your device (it might void the warranty).

And, for the Hola launcher. If it's getting automatically downloaded from the Internet (Google Play Store), then you may disable auto app update or restrict background data to prevent it from getting downloaded.

If it's not getting downloaded from the Internet, then I'm afraid it comes pre-installed (bloatware). You can't uninstall those without rooting your device (voids warranty I repeat).